# i cant update the state in my parent component from my child (class) component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

- It's a recipe app
- My Search (class) component is the child component
- The state in my parent component need to to update to the Search result.
- My API is in a separate component
- I can successfully console.log the result.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    recipes: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    recipesData()
      .then(data => this.setState({ recipes: data.recipes }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Search/>
        <RecipeList data={this.state.recipes} />
      </div>

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    search: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const key = "KEY";
    const url = `https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${key}&q=${
      this.state.search
    }&page=2`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {console.log(res)})
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="search"
            value={this.state.search}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extract handleSubmit into your parent component and pass it via props to Search component e.g

<Search onSearchSubmit={handleSearchSubmit} />
<RecipesList .data={...} />

class Search ... {
  <form onSubmit={props.onSearchSubmit}>.....
}

Actually your Search component could be stateless, and you could handle the change from your parent and then call API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data inside `RecipeList` is passed from the `App` component. And When `Search` component changes, the `RecipeList` will change too.

Therefore, when the `Search` component changed, we have to tell `App` that data had changed.

So the common method is just write  `handleSubmit` in `App` and pass it to `Search`:

Here is a working codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-architecture-ktj3q?fontsize=14

(I mocked the fetch part)

---

Update : I added a functional component version of this, if you are interested.

https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-worker-8s3zi?fontsize=14

More about functional component and Hook : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: thanksssss! had to do a bit of adjustment but now works great.               `...... const url = `https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${key}&q=${search}&page=2`;
   fetch(url)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => {const recipes = data.recipes
    console.log(recipes)
    this.setState({recipes:recipes})
    })
}

  componentDidMount() {
    recipesData()
    .then(data => this.setState({ recipes: data.recipes }))
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can update **parent component** state just by passing an update method to the child component and call that method from **child component** and pass response as a parameter to a method

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    recipes: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {

  }
  updateRecipe = (data) =>{
    this.setState({recipes:data.recipes})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Search update={(data)=>this.updateRecipe(data)}/>
        <RecipeList data={this.state.recipes} />
      </div>
     )}
 }

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    search: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const key = "KEY";
    const url = `https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=${key}&q=${
      this.state.search
    }&page=2`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {this.props.update(res)})
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="search"
            value={this.state.search}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )}

}
```